# Flotr2 different colors for two sets of data

Tags: javascript, colors, flotr2

I've merged positive and negative data to one data set called yAxis (multiple columns for both positive and negative). Here's the code:

```
//...

var yAxis = [wololoTotalValues];
var xAxis = wololoTotalKeys;

window.onload = function () {
    Flotr.draw(document.getElementById("chart"), yAxis, {
        title: "wololo",
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.8
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: wololoMaxValue + 10,
            tickDecimals: 0
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: xAxis
        }
    });
};  

//...
<div id='chart' style="width:1200px;height:500px;"></div>
```

[image: Here's how it looks like now]

I would like 'bad' and 'ble' to be red. I found some manuals how to handle this problem with flot, but not flotr(flotr2).

**Is there any way to make it somehow like below? Or maybe I must split the data like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273055/different-color-bars-for-flot-categories-bar-chart)?**

```
colors: (yAxis[0-lastGood] : "#0000FF"), (yAxis[lastGood+1-lastBad] : "#FF0000")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the solution, splitting the data into two arrays helped. Code is below:

```
            var gud = [];
            for(i=0; i<wololoLengthGood; i++){
                gud.push([i, wololoValuesGood[i]]);
            }

            var bad = [];
            for(i=wololoLengthGood; i<wololoLengthGood+wololoLengthBad; i++){
                bad.push([i, wololoValuesBad[i-wololoLengthGood]]);
            }

            window.onload = function () {
                Flotr.draw(document.getElementById("chart"), 
                [{                         // replacement of 'yAxis' from here
                    data: gud,
                    color: "#0000FF"
                },{
                    data: bad,
                    color: "#FF0000"
                }],                        // till here.
                //...
```